# Transforming vertices, edges or faces affects surrounding areas

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I can't transform vertices, edges or faces without affecting the surrounding areas as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have accidentally enabled [*proportional editing*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html). It can be disabled by clicking on the button shown in the screenshot below or toggled by pressing the <kbd>O</kbd> shortcut when using the default keymap.

[image: Header]
[image: Location in the user interface]